# Why does this Qt app have multiple entries in the application menu?

Tags: macos, qt

What could be the reason my Qt application has multiple entries in the Mac application menu? (I'm building against Qt 4.8 on Mountain Lion)

[image: duplicate entries in application menu]

I've read and re-read the [Mac specific Qt issues](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mac-differences.html), along with [QMenubar on Mac OS X](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x), but can't guess what the cause could be.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide some code?

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't exactly sure what would be relevant. I don't explicitly create those 'Hide' and 'Show All' entries.

Comment: If you are sure it is not your code, then you should report a bug. That is why I asked for your code, because sometimes there is inconsistency between the original intent and the results of actions.

Comment: I see. Yeah I'll file a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an unneeded call to [NSApplicationLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationLoad). This application was recently converted from Carbon to Cocoa, and this call was leftover. Removing it fixed the problem.